# animatedcollapse moving other elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using animatedcollapse to create a menu with divs that expand when clicked. It works but when a div is being collapsed while another one is expanded the following elements are being moved creating a slight shaking effect. I'm pretty sure the solution involves wrapping the collapsable divs in another container but I can't quite get my head around it.

Site:
http://nicholasarehart.com/designs/sites/RCA/expertise/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same Js code for one of my projects there are two solutions:

1. do not have the divs automatically sized when the div is created it
   transitions to the next "toggled" div's size, if you style all of
   the divs to be the same size it should eliminate the transition
   between sizes
2. absolutely position the element so that it does not move, given your
   website this would be the far more complex of the two options.

I used both to fix my issue.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I figured out that setting the height eliminated the problem.